# No TTY after installing NVIDIA Driver

Tags: command-line, nvidia, display, tty

When I first installed Ubuntu 14.04, I used the command line to install the nvidia drivers to my computer. Now, if I try to open any of the 6 TTYs, I lose all display and my monitor cuts off until I exit back to the GUI. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up a terminal in the GUI, and `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.

Add either of the following to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line:

```
nomodeset
```

or

```
vga=xxx
```

Where `xxx` is a VESA screen code that best matches your screen resolution. You can find a list of these [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers).

Once you are done, save the file, and run `sudo update-grub`. Reboot, and the TTYs should be working again.

Comment: As I cannot comment yet, via reply: It's _not_ either - when you use the nvidia driver and grub2's gfxterm, you have to use ```nomodeset``` otherwise you cannot switch to a tty. vga=xxx is optional to change the resolution. Now I'm happy again with tty in 1600x1200 and graphical boot menu :)